# Magento2.3.3 File Validation failed error

Tags: magento2

I am facing error while uploading image in description unde category > Description  in Admin.

I have checked **fileinfo** is already installed

[image]

```
[04-May-2020 09:12:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php:362
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Files.php(60): Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage->getFilesCollection('/mnt/data/home/...', NULL)
#1 /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Files.php(74): Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Content\Files->getFiles()
#2 /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/files.phtml(13): Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Content\Files->getFilesCount()
#3 /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/mnt/data/home/...')
#4 /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\Templat in /mnt/data/home/hostes68/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php on line 362
```

I am totally confused as this error never occurs in my local setup & occurs only on stage setup. Also, it occurs some time on stage & other time it is fine. I am not able to get any proper fix solution for this

Comment: are you getting this error only on the production website? do you have two-three/AWS for server?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **fileinfo** extension in order to use **mime_content_type**. In debian based system you can install it via apt:

> apt-get install php-mime-type

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

The reason is that the mime_content_type is removed in 7.1, and while it is checked to see if it exists the getFileExtension is not retrieving the ext because when the file is uploaded to /tmp directory, it saves it without an extension. So there is now way to ascertain whether the file is valid or not.

installing the fileinfo PHP extension should solve your issue.

In my opinion the fileinfo extension needs to get added to the requirements in the composer.json file of Magento's Framework and the composer.json file of the CMS module

Also check:- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24332

Comment: Here the case is it works some times & sometimes it throws error

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem that the uploaded tmp name does not have the extension.

Go to `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php` and find the metod `_getMimeType()` which looks like:

```
private function _getMimeType()
{
    return $this->fileMime->getMimeType($this->_file['tmp_name']);
}
```

Replace current return value to `return $this->_file['type'];` so it will look like:

```
private function _getMimeType()
{
    return $this->_file['type'];
}
```

and then check if the issue still exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case below function returns image/jpeg  , or image/png this type of value.

```
private function _getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->fileMime->getMimeType($this->_file['tmp_name']);
    }
```

But in the function **checkMimeType($validTypes = [])**, parameter **$validTypes** array contents integer value. so that checking return false.

I modifyed the function **checkMimeType** flowing way:

```
public function checkMimeType($validTypes = [])
    {
        // return if it is not integer value

        if(!is_int($this->_getMimeType())){
            return true;
        }

        if (count($validTypes) > 0) {
            if (!in_array($this->_getMimeType(), $validTypes)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it will helps!