# Images Upload Error In Image Gallery in Magento 2.3.4/5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5

In my server side (live), Image gallery not open, i am trying .png/jpg format only. New images are not being uploaded and do not show the already uploaded image.

i have attached with screen shot.

1. Do not show the already uploaded image
   [image: choose image from folder (already uploaded but not showing)]
2. New images are not being uploaded

[image: and when i upload new image]

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311936/magento2-3-3-file-validation-failed-error

Comment: thanks for share,let me check

Comment: @devidas not work dear